# ERROR 1093 (HY000): You can't specify target table for update in FROM clause

Tags: mysql, sql

I am currently teaching myself mysql and I am trying to delete the lowest paid Employees from my table but I keep getting this error which I don't understand or know how to fix.

```html
delete from Employee
where Salary = (select min(Salary) from Employee)
```

Can someone please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In MySQL, you cannot modify a table and select from the same table in a subquery. This applies to statements such as DELETE, INSERT, REPLACE, UPDATE, and (because subqueries can be used in the SET clause) LOAD DATA.

Try setting the minimum salary record before the query like:

```
SET @min = (SELECT MIN(Salary) FROM Employee);
DELETE FROM Employee WHERE Salary=@min LIMIT 1;
```

Or you could even avoid the first query altogether by creating [another subquery](https://www.davidtan.org/mysql-error-cant-specify-target-table-for-update-in-from-clause-solution/):

```
DELETE FROM Employee
WHERE Salary=(
  SELECT 
    minSalary 
  FROM (SELECT MIN(Salary) AS minSalary FROM Employee) AS alias
) LIMIT 1;
```

[References](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/subqueries.html)

Hope this helps,

Comment: I'm so sorry I made a typo in my question, there is no Participants, just employees. It has been corrected.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using a `JOIN`:

```
delete e
    from Employee e join
         (select min(salary) as min_salary from employee) ee
         on e.salary = ee.min_salary;
```

Note:  I changed `participants` to `employee`.  That makes more sense given what you describe and the error you are getting.

This is a limitation in MySQL.  Your code would work in other databases.

Comment: I'm so sorry I made a typo in my question, there is no Participants, just employees. It has been corrected.

Comment: @It'sLio . . . It is interesting that you prefer a two-statement solution over a one-statement solution.

Answer (score 1):

Try using LIMIT and ORDER BY

```
DELETE FROM Employee
ORDER BY Salary
LIMIT 1;
```

If there are many employees then you need to use a variable

```
SET @MinSalary = (SELECT MIN(Salary) FROM Employee);
DELETE FROM Employee
Where Salary = @MinSalary;
```

Comment: Are you following me?

Comment: @MiroslavGlamuzina looks like we are following the same `sql` tag